# Ionic - Pagination is being hidden with new ion-slides component (Swiper)

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I'm using the `ion-slides` component (Ionic v1.2.4) which uses [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VqtVDPmLSUk) and I'm experiencing issues with the pagination being hidden when too many (> 10) slides are being used.

I've modified this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzx768zp/22/) to demonstrate the problem I'm experiencing, notice if you remove a slide from the HTML the pagination displays accordingly.

Can anybody tell me how to force the pagination to display still?

---

**Update**

This is something Ionic have implemented for whatever reason as pointed out by @nico. They should probably make this configurable leaving it up to the developer on whether the pagination should be hidden after 10 slides.

My solution below is one workaround for now though if anybody wants the pagination to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution which i'll share with everyone in case you have been stuck with this.

What I did was create my own custom pagination as this way the `ng-hide` class doesn't get added, luckily Swiper allows you to do this quite easily.

To do this add a `<div>` element to bind the pagination to like so

```
<ion-slides options="swiper.options" slider="swiper.data.slider">
      <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="item in slides.Tasks" >                              
      </ion-slide-page>                           
</ion-slides>
<div class="custom-swiper-pagination swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Notice the `swiper-pagination` class that I also added, this is Ionic's default class for pagination styling.

And then create the binding in the Swipers options in the controller like this so that pagination stuff will automatically be added under this new `div` container

```
$scope.swiper = {
        options: {
            pagination: '.custom-swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            loop: false,
            direction: 'horizontal',
            spaceBetween: 20,
            speed: 600
        },
        data: {}
};
```

And finally add some CSS to style your new `div` container. I copied the exact stuff from Ionic's css file for horizontal bulleted pagination.

```
.custom-swiper-pagination {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
}

.custom-swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 5px; 
}
```

And here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzx768zp/24/) for a live example.

---

**Update**

Like @nico has pointed out this is not so much an error because a flag is being used `showPager` in conjunction with an `ng-if` to hide the pagination. But it is something people would like control over so it is probably an issue that needs to be made configurable by Ionic.

My solution still works as a temporary fix though if you don't fancy manually editing the Ionic library code.

Some of the raised issues regarding this can be found here [Ionic's GitHub repo](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ion-slides)

Answer (score 5):

Pager is hidden by default, to enable:

```
<ion-slides pager="true">
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/

pager   boolean 
Whether or not to show the pager. Default: false.

Answer (score 1):

It is hardcoded. See line 79 https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/slides.js#L79

Maybe we could pass an option hide-pagination="" which accept boolean or integer for hiding after n- slides and defaults doesn't hide pagination after 10 slides.

This could be done with this [Pull-Request](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/4982) dealing with an related problem.

I will dig into it as I need that feature as well.

Comment: I did notice the `showPager` flag being used inside an `ng-if` which explains the class being added. But like you said I think it should be configurable because it doesn't suit all users at the minute

Comment: I've updated both my answer and question to point out to people that its not really an error, anyway my solution still provides a work around for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ionic 2 (RC.0): On the Slides the bullets did not show up (regardless of how many slides I had) - the "pager" attribute did not work for me.

I realized that the pagination is always hidden.

So my solution/workaround is, to override the hidden class setting in my scss file. Additionally, with the bullet settings below, you get a nice shadow.

```
ion-slides {
    .hide {
        display: block !important; // override "display: none"
    }
    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;
    }
}
```

and my slides look just like this:

```
<ion-slides pager>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```